# How to use all the cores of Solr in solrj

Tags: java, indexing, solr, lucene, solrj

I have downloaded solr 5.2.0 and have started using `$solr_home/bin/solr` start

The Logs stated:

Waiting to see Solr listening on port 8983 [/]
Started Solr server on port 8983 (`pid=17330`). Happy searching!

Then I visited `http://localhost:8983/solr` and created a new core using Core Admin / new Core as Core1 ( using `solr-5.2.0/server/solr/configsets/data_driven_schema_configs/config` for the new core)

Then I have written a java code that indexes a few records

the Code is as follows:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, SolrServerException {

    HttpSolrClient solrClient =  new HttpSolrClient("http://localhost:8983/solr/core1"); //$NON-NLS-1$4
    //HttpSolrClient solrClient =  new HttpSolrClient(args[0]); //$NON-NLS-1$4

    // Empty the database...
    solrClient.deleteByQuery( "*:*" );// delete everything! //$NON-NLS-1$
    System.out.println("cleared"); //$NON-NLS-1$
    ArrayList<SolrInputDocument> docs = new ArrayList<>();

    long starttime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; ++i) { 
        SolrInputDocument doc = new SolrInputDocument();
        doc.addField("bat", "book"+i); //$NON-NLS-1$ //$NON-NLS-2$
        doc.addField("id", "book id -" + i); //$NON-NLS-1$ //$NON-NLS-2$
        doc.addField("name", "The Legend of the Hobbit part 1 " + i); //$NON-NLS-1$ //$NON-NLS-2$
        doc.addField("id1", "book id -" + i); //$NON-NLS-1$ //$NON-NLS-2$
        doc.addField("name1", "The Legend of the Hobbit part 2 " + i); //$NON-NLS-1$ //$NON-NLS-2$
        doc.addField("id2", "book id -" + i); //$NON-NLS-1$ //$NON-NLS-2$

        docs.add(doc);

        if (i % 250000 == 0) {
            solrClient.add(docs);
            System.out.println("added "+ i + "documents"); //$NON-NLS-1$ //$NON-NLS-2$
            docs.clear();
        }
    }
    solrClient.add(docs);
    System.out.println("completed adding to Solr. Now commiting.. Please wait"); //$NON-NLS-1$
    solrClient.commit();
    long endtime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println("process completed in "+(endtime-starttime)/1000+" seconds"); //$NON-NLS-1$ //$NON-NLS-2$
}
```

After running the code , I check
http://localhost:8983/solr/#/~cores/core1
and seen 1000000 documents indexed.

Then I added another core (named core2 in similar fashion to core 1 ) and then again ran the job, this time , I saw that core 2 didnot show any documents , only core 1 still showed.

Can anybody suggest how to use both the cores of solr to distribute and store the document so that I can index data faster, My assumption is that If I increase the number of cores, the speed of Indexing should Increase.

Kindly anybody let me know if any one has tried and succedded in utilizing both the cores and seen performance improvement.

Thanks.

Comment: After fixing the issue with the URL - You're probably better off running the indexing in parallell, instead of having separate cores (which means that your data will be separated into different containers and cross-core queries isn't a good idea).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here in your code it still points to core1.

```
HttpSolrClient solrClient =  new HttpSolrClient("http://localhost:8983/solr/core1"
```

In case you want to have the indexex for core2

you need to change here

```
HttpSolrClient solrClient =  new HttpSolrClient("http://localhost:8983/solr/core2"
```

after this change try run the job, it will index for the core2.

Comment: Hello Abhijit, Thanks for Pointing out my mistake. What I wanted to acheive is to index using both cores,or in other words, is it possible to index using both cores and have replication factor to be 1. My sole aim is to increase the performance of Indexing as I am trying for near real time indexing. The same thing in lucene takes 1/3rd time to execute. can you please suggest any changes..?

Comment: Cores are using to maintain your indexing properly. At high level, for structure. I dont think you can get faster indexing with more cores. And what do you means by 1/3 times in lucene. Solr internally uses lucene. Which things have you compared to arrive at 1/3 time.

Comment: Hi Ramzy, please refer to my post over here  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30823314/lucene-vs-solr-indexning-speed-for-sampe-data here I have written the two codes doing the same tings (one using lucene and other using solr) and the difference between performance, though I was able to improve the speed of Solr today to 80 seconds from 159 seconds by changing the solrconfig.xml, but Lucene was still Faster. Hope it give you more idea about my problem statement. :)